# Do questions need to convey intent

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I recently asked a not-very-well received [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046556/importing-list-iterator) here.

Many people wanted to understand my intent and to tell me what the "right approach" to my real problem was, and insisted that I was facing a "X-Y" problem.

Now my question is, does a question need to communicate intent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, a question does not always need to convey intent.

However, language learners will very commonly try to approach a problem in what more experienced users know is *completely the wrong approach* (what we like to call an X-Y problem).

Of course, this can also happen *to* an experienced user. For example, if I started asking about ASP MVC, I would likely run into a few of these even though I am experienced with C#. If you are asking a question, you clearly are somewhat inexperienced in the area, and could be doing it wrong.

When that happens; we will ask for context in order to determine if indeed there is a much better way to go about the overall task. Users that do so are really trying to help, so providing the context is always nice in these cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've experienced similar frustrations answering learner questions, but does this apply to experienced users as well, not just language learners?

Comment: @simonzack We all make mistakes; and since a person is asking, I find it it fair to assume that they are not an expert in doing whatever they are asking about, so it still applies.

Answer (score 7):

A question, in general, does not need to convey intent.

Your question, in particular, does.

Why?

You're asking for something that doesn't have any obvious reason to be needed -- that means that the more information you give, the easier it is for us to help you solve your actual problem.  Is your actual problem that you need that exposed? Probably not, it's probably to have that exposed in the course of solving some other problem.

You can always choose not to disclose the intent, but if you start having to ask more questions because you didn't disclose the intent, then you've sort of proven the need to disclose intent.

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't *need* to, it just frequently ends up resulting in answers that aren't actually helpful, or at least answers that aren't nearly as helpful as they could be, and potentially results in answers that are actively harmful.

These people are asking for additional context so that they can better help you solve your problem, and to avoid causing additional problems for *you* by only pushing you further away from fixing your problem.

If you don't want to provide this context though, it's your loss.  The question of course still needs to be answerable without that context (if the context is necessary to make an answer *possible*, then of course it can't be omitted).