# How to deal with "make this code more functional"/"how do I do this in a functional style"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, subjective-questions

I frequent the functional programming tag and often see questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422516/how-would-you-write-the-condition-in-ramda) where the OP is asking how to do something something functional programming (or how to do something using a functional library something something functional programming).

The problem is that while you *can* convert the code to use functional calls/expressions/composition instead of a more imperative style frequently the code already works and/or changing it to a more functional style arguably makes it *worse* (less readable/maintainable, vendor-locked on specific libraries, etc. for *little or no benefit*).

I mean, I'm as in to functional programming as the next person (I frequent the tag for a reason) and think it's a great step forward in general for correctness, code reuse through composition, etc. But too often these requests seem buzzword-bingo/cargo-cult incantation kinds of things.

I realize this is not necessarily unique to functional programming (I'm sure if Stack Overflow had been around in it's current incarnation in 1997 it would have been "how do I do something something object-oriented?") but since it's the current "in thing" in some circles it seems to be drawing more than its fair share of such questions.

Generally if the question is a solid question by the site's rules I'll try to answer it with a caveat not to put the cart before the horse (make it functional for the sake of checking off the buzzword list). If the question is objectively awful for another reason I'll deal with it for that (e.g. no MCVE). But the reason I'm asking this question is I see a lot of these as being in a grey area. Consider the question I linked. You could treat it as

- Belonging on Code Review instead of here
- Too broad
- Opinion-based

None of those are necessarily *wrong*, but none of them are a perfect fit either and I have both used and seen others use a mix in practice. You could also just say "meh it's not great but good enough" and answer it.

So should I vote to close? If so for what reason? Can I apply that reason in principled fashion to such questions or is it case-by-case? Let it slide? Let it slide but leave a comment? Is there a stock comment that is used for stuff like this (the way there is for MVCE for example)?

If the answer is that there is no answer that's fine, I'll keep doing what I've been doing, but I see this often enough I wanted to ask.

Comment: That looks like a pretty legitimate question to me.  At least you filter this one by adding [ramda.js] to your profile's Ignored Tags section.  That however isn't all that likely to always work well when you subscribe to an [everything-and-half-the-kitchen-sink] tag.  Consider to filter that one as well and be more specific about the library and language tags you like.

Comment: @HansPassant I use ramda at work, have no problem with it. My objection is that I don't think it's that legit of a question: OP was trying to remove `if/else` because... reasons? I mean, JavaScript has a ternary operator. Again, I chose this because I consider it an edge case. If it were just a text dump with "how do I make this more functional" I'd VTC no question (tag gets plenty of those). If it were "how do I get this compositional pipeline correct? It outputs y for input x and I want z" I'd answer it.

Comment: I don't think it matters why the OP wanted to remove if/else.  Or, more generally, why he wants to make the code more functional.  It is not a totally misguided thing to want to do.  So let him ask his question, and let someone answer.  *"So should I vote to close?"* - IMO, no.  There are objective answers possible, no MCVE is required, it is not overly broad .....

Comment: I tend to agree with @StephenC . Like "what have you tried?", "what is your intent?" should be asked aiming at some other goal (typically making the question clearer or better scoped), and not as an expression of a self-standing requirement. See also: [*Do questions need to convey intent*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277457/2751851), which includes some discussion on XY-ness, one specific setting in which asking for intent might be illuminating (and even then, note that XY-ness doesn't justify closure).

Answer (score 9):

Worth remembering that code review / technique questions aren't actually *off-topic* here, even though there are multiple other sites that are dedicated to specific aspects of analyzing / improving working code.

If it was, we'd have many thousands of heavily-used posts to get rid of, and that seems like a waste.

Now... [These are the guidelines for avoiding opinion-based questions:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

> avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

On top of that, questions are expected to be reasonably scoped and specific.

So to answer your question... If the "make this more functional" question isn't reasonably scoped or specific, or fails one or more of the tests in that bullet list... Then either edit it to be specific and focused on an answerable problem, or close it.

Comment: What's your favorite programming paradigm? I use OOP for everything, what do you use? FP sucks, am I right? I'm curious if other people feel like I do. What if FP died out?

Comment: It should be noted, however, that there *is* a site here for [codereview.se], and that it was established for...well, code review. Just as [su] didn't exist and that category of question used to be acceptable here but isn't any longer, it may be a good idea to start encouraging posters to use it instead for those sorts of question.

Comment: I did note the existence of other sites, @ken (Software Engineering is relevant here too). But, they aren't quite equivalent to SU - non-programming computer use questions were not well tolerated on SO even prior to SU's debute. Technique questions have a bit of a different struggle on SO.

Comment: But the questions existed here, and they weren't all migrated over to SU when the site was created. They are still here now, and are often used by new users as an objection to off-topic close votes. There's no reason that suggesting that code review questions be asked at CR should be discouraged. If that site is going to grow to do what it was intended to do, we should be advising users to post there.

Comment: @KenWhite only problem I have with that is, well, consider Haskell. There aren't a lot of Haskell programmers period. Only a handful of those are SO regulars. How many are going to see my post on CodeReview? CodeReview is fine for Java, C, JavaScript, Python, etc. but many functional languages languish in a less resource-laden spectrum of the programming community. I realize that there's a chicken-and-egg problem here: we don't send people to CodeReview so people don't pay attention to CodeReview so we don't send people there. I'm just not sure how to solve it.

Comment: @JaredSmith: We solve that chicken/egg problem the way we did when SU was started. We refer questions to that site. Haskell programmers should be able to find it, especially when they start noticing the *This question was migrated to...* banners. I don't see why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @JaredSmith [haskell] regular who is unlikely to become active in CodeReview in the foreseeable future checking in. Hi! o/ (Nothing against CodeReview, of course, it is a perfectly fine site.)

Comment: @KenWhite I feel the really important questions are (1) Will Stack Overflow benefit from proscribing those questions? (2) Will CodeReview benefit from having all those questions migrated to it? On the latter point, while [CodeReview appears to be accepting of questions about short snippets](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1583) like the one showcased here, there seems to be enough ambivalence to make me doubt the community there would enjoy a large influx of questions of this sort. Furthermore, as it stands I don't see signs of CodeReview being languishing due to lack of questions.